# sbt-assembly | NoSuchMethodError at runtime when shading

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, uberjar

I'm trying to use `sbt-assembly` for shading some dependencies.
I've `shaded` and published a jar for project `X` as mentioned in the `sbt-assembly` github [readme file](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#q-despite-the-concerned-friends-i-still-want-publish-%C3%BCber-jars-what-advice-do-you-have).
When I'm trying to use that published jar in project `Y`, I'm getting `NoSuchMethodError` error at `runtime`.

Below are my shade rules used for project `X`

```
 val shadePackage = "mycompany.spark.v1.shaded"
  Seq(
    ShadeRule.rename("cats.**" -> s"$shadePackage.cats.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("com.mycompany.sdk.scala.**" -> s"$shadePackage.sdk.scala.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> s"$shadePackage.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("fs2.**" -> s"$shadePackage.fs2.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("io.circe.**" -> s"$shadePackage.io.circe.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("jawn.**" -> s"$shadePackage.jawn.@1").inAll, <==============
    ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> s"$shadePackage.shapeless.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("sttp.client3.**" -> s"$shadePackage.sttp.client3.@1").inAll,
  )
```

For `jawn`, When I use the below shade rule,

```
ShadeRule.rename("jawn.**" -> s"$shadePackage.jawn.@1").inAll
```

it gives me the below error at runtime for project `Y` which includes project `X` jar as a dependency.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.typelevel.jawn.Facade.$init$(Lorg/typelevel/jawn/Facade;)V
```

But when I use the shade rule as below, it works fine.

```
ShadeRule.rename("org.typelevel.jawn.**" -> s"$shadePackage.org.typelevel.jawn.@1").inAll,
```

In project `Y`, I'm using the below dependencies which have transitive dependencies with `jawn`

```
val CirceVersion = "0.14.0"
val Http4sVersion = "0.22.2"

"org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-client" % Http4sVersion,
"org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % Http4sVersion,

"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % CirceVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-derivation" % CirceVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-literal" % CirceVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % CirceVersion,
```

I would appreciate if anyone could explain whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by shading as below

```
assemblyShadeRules := {
  val shadePackage = "shaded"
  Seq(
    ShadeRule.rename("cats.**" -> s"$shadePackage.cats.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> s"$shadePackage.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("fs2.**" -> s"$shadePackage.fs2.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("io.circe.**" -> s"$shadePackage.io.circe.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("org.typelevel.jawn.**" -> s"$shadePackage.org.typelevel.jawn.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> s"$shadePackage.shapeless.@1").inAll,
    ShadeRule.rename("sttp.client3.**" -> s"$shadePackage.sttp.client3.@1").inAll,
  )
},
```

and making a new project in sbt as,

```
lazy val fatJar = project.settings(
  commonSettings,
  name := "my-project-fat",
  Compile / packageBin := (library / assembly).value
)
```

`sbt packageBin` will create run the `assembly` phase and create the fat-jar

Details can also be found [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#publishing-not-recommended).